# Angular2 Error: Unexpected value 'AuthGuard' exported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Im battling to find a solution for this issue I'm facing. I am trying to put guards on a specific route I have set up in a external routing file. This guard is to check that the user is logged in in order to access this route or the user is redirected to the login screen.

This is my app.module.ts file:

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; 
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal'; 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
import { Routing } from './app.routing';


import { LoginComponent } from './shared/login/login.component'; 
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';


import { AuthGuard } from './shared/login/auth-guard.service'; 
import { AuthService } from './shared/login/auth.service';

    @NgModule({
        bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            LoginComponent,
            DashboardComponent
        ],
        imports: [
            UniversalModule,
            Routing
        ],
        exports: [
            AuthGuard,
            AuthService
        ] }) export class AppModule { }
```

I thought importing the auth-gaurd.service and auth.service and exporting both would be needed as if I exclude them from the export I get a error saying that AuthGuard needs to be exported.

This is my routing file:

```
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './shared/login/auth-guard.service';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './shared/login/login.component';


export const Routing = RouterModule.forRoot([ 
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }, 
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
])
```

Finally this is my AuthGuard service which communicates with the auth service which has `isLoggedIn` set to true if the user is logged in.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _router: Router) {

    }

    canActivate() { // Route gaurd
        if (this._authService.isLoggedIn) { 
            return true;
        } else {
            this._router.navigate(['login']); 
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the stack error message:

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Unexpected value 'AuthGuard' exported by the module 'AppModule'
at G:\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14153:33
at Array.forEach (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (G:\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14136:46)
at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (G:\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16803:49)
at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (G:\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16741:39)
at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (G:\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16732:23)
at NodePlatform.bootstrapModule (G:\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.js:436:25)
at NodePlatform.serializeModule (G:\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.js:108:22)
at G:\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:74:63
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (G:\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\HaldanMT-WebApp\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:232:26)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add `AuthGuard` and `AuthService` in `providers` section in ngModule, not in `exports` or look this tutorial for [ROUTING & NAVIGATION](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) from angular team.

Sample of code from tutorial:

```
import { AuthGuard }                from '../auth-guard.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            children: [
              { path: 'crises', component: ManageCrisesComponent },
              { path: 'heroes', component: ManageHeroesComponent },
              { path: '', component: AdminDashboardComponent }
            ],
          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule {}
```